# Getting error no 1004 while running VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I was running a VBA code in Excel 2007. I got the above mention run/Application error of 1004.

My code is

```
Public Sub LblImport_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vData As Variant, vCleanData As Variant, vFile As Variant, sMarket As String
Dim wbkExtract As Workbook, sLastCellAddress As String, month As String
Dim cnCountries As New Collection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Get the name of the Dataview Extract file to transform and the market name

vFile = "D:\DRX\" & "Norvasc_Formatted.xlsx"

sMarket = "Hypertension"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("TherapeuticMarket").Value = "Hypertension"

'   Clear all existing data from this workbook

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells.ClearContents


'   Create labels in Raw Data Sheet

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Therapy Market"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Country"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Brand"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Corporation"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Molecule"

'   Open Dataview extract, copy and clean data

Set wbkExtract = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
i = 2
Do While wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value <> ""

    If UCase(Mid(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, 1, 3)) = "TRX" Then
        month = Split(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, "/")(1)
        If Len(month) = 1 Then
            month = "0" + month
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, i + 4).Value = Mid(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,     i).Value, 1, 10) + month + "/" + Mid(Split(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, "/")(2), 3, 2)
    End If
    If UCase(Mid(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, 1, 3)) = "LCD" Then
        month = Split(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, "/")(2)
        If Len(month) = 1 Then
            month = "0" + month
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, i + 4).Value = Mid(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, 1, 14) + month + "/" + Mid(Split(wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value, "/")(3), 3, 2)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
vData = wbkExtract.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
wbkExtract.Close savechanges:=False
vCleanData = CleanRawData(vData, sMarket)
sLastCellAddress = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(UBound(vCleanData, 1) + 1, UBound(vCleanData, 2)).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Range("A2:" & sLastCellAddress).Value = vCleanData

'   Get List of Unique Countries

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To UBound(vCleanData, 1)
    cnCountries.Add vCleanData(i, 2), vCleanData(i, 2)
Next i

On Error GoTo 0

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Country"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Group 1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Group 2"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Group 3"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Group 4"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Range("A1:G1").Font.Bold = True

For i = 1 To cnCountries.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = cnCountries.Item(i)
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: which line is causing the problem?  Did you try stepping through the code in the debugger to see what was happening when the error is thrown?

Comment: It just throws this error at no line whatever.. Instantly.. Thats most puzzling.

Comment: So if you put a break point on the first line of code, and try to run this code, you don't even reach the breakpoint?

Comment: can you run through each line with a break point and `F8`? you will find it..

Comment: yeah.. When I put a break-point and run still show error

Comment: Also this code was used in Excel 2003.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't even get to the first line, then your problem is problem is likely in the code that calls this `Sub`.  I put it into Excel 2010 (don't have 2007 handy) and it got past the first line.

Comment: But it is not working in my case. OK I will check again.

Comment: First thought - If you're in Excel 2003, will it give you the error in trying to open an XLSX file??

Comment: Did you try to compile your code? It looks like a compile error to me. If you don't know how to do this, open the VBE, the select Debug > Compile. This will check against compile errors in the code (not run-time though). It will also take you to the direct line where the compile error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a broken code cache.

I've seen errors happen like this before in older format (xls) workbooks and it can be a sign of problems in the file overall.

Try the compile option suggested by @Scott Holtzman first.  In some cases I've seen the recompile not work and if that happens just force a compile by making a change to the code.  A trivial change is enough usually.

If that doesn't work then (to help disagnose a corruption issue) try copying the code into a new workbook and see what happens there.  If it runs in the new sheet then I wouldn't waste more time on it and just rebuild the sheet, trust me it'll be quicker than messing about troublshooting the one you have.